# Uniform most powerful Test for one-sided hypothesis

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

> I am looking at the proof of the following theorem from Morris H. DeGroot and Mark J. Schervish's probability and statistics. I am having trouble in understanding part of the proof, which I have highlighted them on the pictures. The theorem correspond to the hypothesis $H_0:θ\leθ_0 \, vs \, H_1:θ\gtθ_0$.

---

[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]

---

> I am trying to understand this proof above. What I am confusing is
>
> (1)At the beginning of the proof, it seems to create a new hypothesis $H_0:θ=θ' \, vs \, H_1:θ=θ''$ for $θ',θ''$. My question is the power function $\pi(θ'|\delta)$ on formula (9.3.10) is correspond to the original hypothesis or the new one?
>
> (2) At the end of the proof, the author claimed that $\delta ^*$ maximize the power function at $\theta ''$. Under my understanding, the test procedure  $\delta ^*$ has the largest type I error and smallest type II error for any other procedures $\delta$ that satisfy $a(\delta) \le a(\delta^*)$. But I do not understand how does it connected to the author's conclusion.
>
> Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.